# Change from jQuery to Plain Javascript in Post Request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace all the jQuery dependency with plain javascript in the following post request.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
     $.post("test_post.php",
        {
                name: "John Doe",
                age: "42"
        },
        function(data, textStatus)
        {
                alert("Response from server: " + data);
        });
});
</script>
```

Any ideas how?

Comment: Just for learning, you can see this site with a lot of examples http://youmightnotneedjquery.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can play around, but this is the basic example:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'test_post.php?name=john+doe&age=41', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    // Success!
    alert(request.responseText);
  } else {
    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  // There was a connection error of some sort
};

request.send();
```